# importance of the study of orthogonality in normed linear spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I am interested in studying the notions of orthogonality in normed linear spaces. In many literature I find that orthogonality in normed linear spaces is used to characterize inner product spaces and also used in best approximation.

Since I came across many papers on this subject, the question is:

What is the importance of the notion of orthogonality in normed linear spaces? And any other applications apart from the ones I mentioned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orthogonality can be a useful property when you are trying to find a basis. Normally you scale vectors so that the basis vectors have norm $1$, which simplifies expressions.

Also for proving that a decomposition is unique.